# Talend : get the name of the file of tFileInputDelimited in tSystem

Tags: java, talend

I am trying to invoke a java program I built inside Talend. One of its argument is the name (or `path\name`) of the TSV file it will be working on. So, I did this Job:

[image: job]

With the `tFileInputDelimited` looking like this:

[image: tFileInputDelimited]

And the `tSystem` looking like that:

[image: tSystem]

Basically, I need to run the following command in `tSystem`:

```
"java -cp * tsvTranspositer.TSVTransposer " + fileName
```

With `fileName` being the Name (path) of the precedent `tFileInputDelimited`
But the `fileName` variable doesn't seem to be callable (as seen on the last screenshot) while I have been told it was. How can I access it from inside `tSystem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to read the file, you need just to pass the file name to the `tSystem` component using a `tFileList`

```
tFileList-----(iterate)----->tSystem
```

In `tSystem` component, concatenate the global var to your command:

```
"java -cp * tsvTranspositer.TSVTransposer "+((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))
```

By this way, your job will iterate over all your input files.

Comment: Seems like a good solution to me. I'll try this tomorrow and yes, at the end, it was supposed to receive a tFileList in entry, so, another problem solved, thank you.